# Different Confusion Matrix with Cross-Validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, confusion-matrix

I am sorry if this is a long post, but i have some questions related to Confusion Matrix metric and Cross-Validation that i really need help with.

This picture from Sklearn CV [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html), shows that our whole dataset should be split into train and test. Then, the train set is split again into a validation part and we train our model in k-1 folds and validate in the remaining one (repeat this k times). And lastly, we test our model with the test set from the beggining.

[image]

In my problem, i have a dataset for a unbalanced binary classification problem with `42372` samples. `3615` belong to class `1`, the rest are class `0`.

Since my dataset is unbalanced, i was using `StratifiedShuffleSplit` with `5 folds`, and got this:

[image]

As result, using a `MLPClassfier` i got the following confusion matrix:

[image]

As you can see from that matrix, half my dataset is being used for test (`19361+19+1782+28 = 21190`).

After this, i changed the CV strategy, and tried `StratifiedKfold`:

[image]

And, as Confusion Matrix, i got this:

[image]

As you can see from this second confusion matrix, my whole dataset is being used for test (`38644+113+3329+286 = 42372`).

So, here are my questions:

1 - Do i need to split my whole data into train/test (e.g., using `train_test_split`), and then feed CV iterators (`KFold`, `StratifiedKFold`, `StratifiedShuffleSplit`, etc) **only** with the train part? Or should i feed my whole data into the iterators and they will do the job of splitting it into train/test and split again this train into train and validation?

2 - About the CV strategies i tried, why `StratifiedShuffleSplit` is using half the data? and why `StratifiedKFold` uses all the data? Any of those CV is wrong? Are both wrong or are both correct? What i am missing here?

**EDIT**: The original code to generate the Confusion Matrix i found [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/generation-of-a-concatenated-confusion-matrix-in-cross-validation-912485c4a972). I have just modified it a little bit to fit my needs, and here it goes:

```
import itertools
import time as time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
# from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

n_splits = 5  # Num of Folds
stratshufkfold = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=n_splits, random_state=0)
# stratshufkfold = KFold(n_splits=n_splits)

def generate_confusion_matrix(cnf_matrix, classes, normalize=False, title='Matriz de Confusão'):
    if normalize:
        cnf_matrix = cnf_matrix.astype('float') / cnf_matrix.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        print("Matriz de confusão normalizada")
    else:
        print('Matriz de confusão, sem normalização')

    plt.imshow(cnf_matrix, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.get_cmap('Blues'))
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()

    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)

    fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
    thresh = cnf_matrix.max() / 2.

    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cnf_matrix.shape[0]), range(cnf_matrix.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, format(cnf_matrix[i, j], fmt), horizontalalignment="center",
                 color="white" if cnf_matrix[i, j] > thresh else "black")

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('Real')
    plt.xlabel('Predito')

    return cnf_matrix


def plot_confusion_matrix(predicted_labels_list, y_test_list):
    cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test_list, predicted_labels_list)
    np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

    # Plot non-normalized confusion matrix
    plt.figure()
    generate_confusion_matrix(cnf_matrix, classes=class_names, title='Matriz de confusão, sem normalização')
    plt.show()

    # Plot normalized confusion matrix
    plt.figure()
    generate_confusion_matrix(cnf_matrix, classes=class_names, normalize=True, title='Matriz de confusão normalizada')
    plt.show()

def evaluate_model_MLP(x, y):
    predicted_targets = np.array([])
    actual_targets = np.array([])
    global t_inicial_MLP
    global t_final_MLP
    t_inicial_MLP = time.time()
    for train_ix, test_ix in stratshufkfold.split(x, y):
        train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y = x[train_ix], y[train_ix], x[test_ix], y[test_ix]

        # Fit
        classifier = MLPClassifier(activation='relu', batch_size=56, solver='sgd').fit(train_x, train_y)

        
        predicted_labels = classifier.predict(test_x)

        predicted_targets = np.append(predicted_targets, predicted_labels)
        actual_targets = np.append(actual_targets, test_y)
    t_final_MLP = time.time()
    return predicted_targets, actual_targets


predicted_target_MLP, actual_target_MLP = evaluate_model_MLP(x, y)
plot_confusion_matrix(predicted_target_MLP, actual_target_MLP)
acuracia_MLP = accuracy_score(actual_target_MLP, predicted_target_MLP)
```

Comment: For the first point, the first option is the way to go. For your second question, imo, it is difficult to say what's happening without having a look at your code. Therefore, I'd suggest to add a piece of code so as to make your example reproducible.

Comment: @amiola I have edited the post with the code. The only thing i am unable to share is the database. But as i said, it is a binary classification problem with shape `(42372, 1036)` where the first `3615` samples belong to class `1` and the rest to class `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified within the comment, for what concerns the first question, the first option is the way to go. Namely, splitting the whole dataset via `train_test_split` and then calling method `.split()` of the chosen cross-validator object on the *training set*.

For the second point, the issue is hidden behind some default parameters of `StratifiedKFold` and `StratifiedShuffleSplit` and on the sligthly different meaning of parameter `n_splits`.

- For what concerns `StratifiedKFold`, the parameter `n_splits` identifies the *number of folds* you're considering as per [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html). Therefore, imposing `n_splits=5` means that the model will be trained on 4-folds (80% of the training set) and tested on one fold (20% of the training set), for each possible combination.
- For what concerns `StratifiedShuffleSplit`, the parameter `n_splits` specifies the *number of reshuffling and splitting iterations*. On the other side, it is the parameter `train_size` (together with `test_size`) to define how big the folds will be (relatively to the size of the training set). In particular, according to the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html), the default setting defines that, if none of them is specified, `train_size=0.9` (90% of the training set) and `test_size=0.1` (10% of the training set).
  Therefore specifying `test_size` within the `StratifiedShuffleSplit` constructor - eg - should solve your problem:

  `stratshufkfold = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=n_splits, random_state=0, test_size=0.2)`